# how do you reuse fb access tokens after the redirect in php

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I've just gotten started with the latest facebook SDK (5.0). It's been a number of years since I last used it, and there's one thing I can't seem to get around...

Following the example code they have here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0

I'm able to get a perfectly working login. My problem is, how do you keep this login alive on the next page load when you aren't being redirected back from facebook?

you used to be able to store the user access token, then reuse that token to keep the session authenticated. In version 5.0 of the SDK, I'm not seeing a way to do that, and i'm pretty lost how you remain logged in.

I wouldn't be asking this here, but I've been looking for a couple days now and have found an abundance of articles using older code that doesn't line up with the current 5.0 sdk I'm trying to use. I'm guessing this is something small that I've been missing or over looking, but I'd love any information you guys can give me.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the exemple in the link you give, there is this line:

`$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;`, so the access token is stored in the PHP session and then accessible from page to page.

You can also store it in your database as a field in your users table.

Below great upgrade guides:

- [Facebook PHP SDK v3.x to v5.x](https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v3-x-to-v5)
- [Facebook PHP SDK v4.0 to v5](https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v4-to-v5)

Comment: I assume two potential routes from here. Once I have the access token, I just make requests with it, and when they start failing, assume that the access token is no longer valid, lol. Or once I have the access token, I need to verify/authenticate/renew it with facebook. I was expecting some kind of "setAccessToken()" or "verifyAccessToken()" function for sites that store the access token. I haven't seen much documentation on this specifically. The examples only go as far as assigning it to a session variable to be reused, but they don't show how to reuse saved access token.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but I just wanted to leave an answer as a record. From [FB official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0):

#### Configuration options

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_access_token' => '{access-token}',
  'enable_beta_mode' => true,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
  'http_client_handler' => 'guzzle',
  'persistent_data_handler' => 'memory',
  'url_detection_handler' => new MyUrlDetectionHandler(),
  'pseudo_random_string_generator' => new MyPseudoRandomStringGenerator(),
]);
```

> If you don't provide a default_access_token in the configuration
>   options, or you wish to use a different access token than the default,
>   you can explicitly pass the access token as an argument to the get(),
>   post(), and delete() methods.

```
$res = $fb->get('/me', '{access-token}');
$res = $fb->post('/me/feed', ['foo' => 'bar'], '{access-token}');
$res = $fb->delete('/{node-id}', '{access-token}');
```